# How to show the diff specific to a named branch in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Assuming I have a named branch foo with two commits a, b:

```
      a       b       c  
------o-------o-------o------- # default
       \          d         e
        ----------o---------o  # branch foo
```

I want to see the diff between a and e (a not included). I could of course use the revision id, but that's not very practical. In git, one can just do git diff master..foo. How can I do the same in hg ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it using [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets).

In your specific example I think you could get a list of of just `d` and `e` using:

```
hg log -r "branch('foo') - branch('default')"
```

where that `-` is defined as:

```
"x - y"
      Changesets in x but not in y.
```

Getting the diff from a to e could be done as:

```
hg diff -r "ancestor(default, foo)" -r foo
```

though there's possibly a shorthand for that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Thanks, this at least give a way to do it automatically. But I am a bit puzzled by the predicate branch(foo). hg log -r "branch(foo)" does what I want, bug hg diff -r "branch(foo)" does not. Do you know why ?

Comment: Because it just filters all changesets by that predicate. "branch(foo)" would return (d, e) which is relatively meaningless in this context.

Comment: The correct syntax seems to be:

    `hg log -r "branch('foo') - branch(default)"`

Comment: If you're on the tip of 'foo', you can do the diff with simply `hg diff -r "ancestor(default, .)"`

Answer (score 12):

Another way to do this, useful also for branches that you have already merged to default is:

```
hg diff -r "max(ancestors(foo) and branch(default)):foo"
```

Though that can be a pit of a pain, so i'd recommend setting up an alias by adding something like:

```
[alias]
branchdiff = diff -r "max(ancestors('$1') and branch(default)):'$1'"
```

To your Mercurial.INI/hgrc which you can then use like this:

```
hg branchdiff <branch name>
```

or

```
hg branchdiff .
```

Comment: It would be great to see an explanation of how exactly HG achieves the desired result with this revset `"max(ancestors(foo) and branch(default)):foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want logs from current branch only:

hg log -b .

Answer (score 0):

diff between branches:

`hg diff -r <branchname_1>:<branchname_2>`

show current branch's latest commit:

`hg log -r .`