# mercurial - see changes on the branch ignoring all the merge commits

Tags: mercurial, branch, diff, branching-and-merging

I have a branch that was developed for a long period of time.  During the development default branch was merged into that branch several times.  I would like now to review all the changes done on that branch ignoring merges, to decide whether it is safe to merge it to default.

I tried

`hg diff -r "branch('myBranch') - merge()"`

but it still shows changes introduced by merges.  Also tried following this [How to show the diff specific to a named branch in mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731190/how-to-show-the-diff-specific-to-a-named-branch-in-mercurial) but

`hg diff -r "branch('myBranch') - branch('default')"`

still bring changes introduced by merges.

Answer (score 7):

You **have** to read about [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) syntax

Your case

`hg log -r "branch('myBranch') and ! merge()"`

Comment: Thanks @lazy-badger, but I'm afraid that produces output not different to  
`hg diff -r "branch('myBranch') - merge()"`  

I still see changes introduced by merges.  
  
BTW you meant `hg diff -r "branch('myBranch') and ! merge()"`, didn't you?

Comment: @Swiety 1) `log` and `diff` are different commands, **TOTALLY DIFFERENT COMMANDS** 2) When I wrote `log` - I wrote `log`, because you have to get **list of changesets** and test changes **in every changeset in set** (*more* than single diff, diff -c for each revision in set of `log`) 3) RTFM "Formal Logic": `x - y` != `x and !y` !!! **(Changesets in x but not in y) != (Changesets in x and not in y)** - back to school

Comment: My formal logic isn't great, but in this instance don't `x - y` and `x and !y` give the same result?  Anything in `myBranch` that isn't also a merge?

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your commands is that when you perform a `hg diff` and pass it several changesets, you actually perform a diff between those changesets, hence you will see the merge result.

If you want to see just the changes made by the changesets then you could use `export`:

```
$ hg export -r "branch('mybranch') and not merge()"
// lists the changes made by each changeset
```

For easier reviewing, you can output these to files with names based on the revision/changeset id:

```
$ hg export -r "branch('mybranch') and not merge()" -o "%H.patch"
```

... creates a file for each non-merge changeset in `mybranch`, and outputs it to a file with the name "40-digit changeset id.patch".  If you'd prefer the revision number (only useful for your local repository as revision id's are local), use `"%R.patch"`.

Answer (score 3):

The following uses the `log` command but with the `--patch` parameter it can show the modified lines as well:

```
hg log --branch my-branch --no-merges --patch
```

Short form:

```
hg log -Mpb my-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a very good question, which I am trying to find good answer for a long time, and yet not found a good one. OK, one thing which 100% works is this:

```
hg status     # make sure that you don't have local changes
hg up <target_branch>
hg merge <your branch>
hg diff > merge.diff
hg up -C  # this one cleans the merge
```

I use this workflow all the time, but it does not satisfy me fully because it requires to switch branches (when I actually might not want to do actual merge right at this exact moment, I am just checking whats there)

I've been searching for ages for a good solution here, but so far there are none found. Tried those:

```
hg diff -r "branch('.') and ! merge()"  # this page
hg diff -r "default:branch('.') and not merge()"
hg diff -r "parents(branch(.)):branch('.') and not merge()"
```

This problem also discussed in:

- [Mercurial: how can I see only the changes introduced by a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919130/mercurial-how-can-i-see-only-the-changes-introduced-by-a-merge)
  which has good answer as: "so if you can define it unambiguously you might convince one of us Mercurial contributors that read SO to implement it."

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    hg diff -r"ancestor(default,my_branch)" -rmy_branch
```

If you haven't done any merges to the branch, then "ancestor" will pick up the original branch point.  If you've done merges, then "ancestor" will pick up the latest merge point.

For example, on the graph below you'll get the diff between 520 and 519:

```
@  521 (default)
|
| o  520 (my_branch)
|/|
o |  519
| |
o |  518
| |
o |  517
| |
| o  516
| |
| o  515
| |
| o  514
|/
o  513
```

On the simpler graph below you'll get a diff between 516 and 513:

```
@  517 (default)
|
| o  516 (my_branch)
| |
| o  515
| |
| o  514
|/
o  513
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Matt Mackall](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Generating-diffs-without-merged-in-changes-tp3630147p3630470.html) what you probably want is:

`hg diff -r mainbranchrev -r mywork`

He writes:

> You may be under the impression that "a changeset is a delta" or 
>   similar, and that this means that Mercurial can magically chain together 
>   a bunch of non-contiguous deltas to construct a bigger delta that's just 
>   your changes.
>
> In fact, Mercurial is much simpler than that. A changeset is actually a 
>   snapshot: a complete set of complete files representing the state of the 
>   project at the time of commit. And a diff is simply the difference 
>   between these two snapshots. So when you do:
>
> hg stat --rev '3408::3575 and user(mdiamond) and not merge()'
>
> ..status simply uses the first and last changesets of the resulting set 
>   to do its calculation.
>
> When you do incremental merges on your development branch, you're 
>   inextricably tangling your work with mainline development, and Mercurial 
>   is not nearly smart enough to untangle it in the way you're asking. Your 
>   best bet is to compare the head of your work with the head of the main 
>   branch:
>
> hg diff -r mainbranchrev -r mywork
>
> ..which will show all your work plus whatever merge fixups you had to 
>   do.